# Switching regulator startup voltage and sag

Tags: power-supply, switching-regulator

I have designed my first voltage regulator circuit using LMR33630ADDA. When supplied with input while not loaded, it produces a very good 5V. If I have a load of ~20mA attached when input is applied, the voltage out is only 2.3V. If I then remove the load and reconnect it, the regulator picks up and continues supplying the correct voltage even with the load. However, at about 100mA load, the voltage begins to droop with increasing load.

I'm sure I have made a simple newbie mistake, but I can't figure out what. All feedback welcome.

[image: Schematic]

The bottom layer in this area is solid ground plane. 8 vias under thermal pad.

[image: Layout]

Comment: Your L1 is connected to the wrong pin.

Answer (score 1):

@DKNguyen was spot on. Thank you very much for taking the time to point out the mistake.

L1 above should have been connected to SW but was connected to the other pad of Cboot1, BOOT.

The whole time the entire circuit was running off the bootstrap voltage.